# How do I deploy Inertiajs in a shared host like hostinger or cpanel?

Tags: php, laravel, localhost, host, inertiajs

I want to deploy Interiajs in Cpanel or hostinger but I don't know how to run it, npm run dev with these hosts, also in the localhost is not run until i run npm run dev, is there anyone know how to start the project without NPM run dev every time? I don't want to deploy projects in netlify or Heroku or in localhost I just want run it by going to localhost/path/public.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command `npm run build` this will build you assets.
With `npm run dev` you app is listening to vite server on `localhost:3000`